# How can I call a function from a custom js to my Vue component method

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to copy a drag and drop task like trello [link](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/using-javascript-to-create-trello-like-card-re-arrange-and-drag-and-drop-557e60125bb4)

Now, how can I call `dragdrop.js`'s function inside `MyComponent.vue`'s method?

Here's what I did...

MyComponent.vue

```
  <template> 
    ....simple html drag and drop structure goes here
  </template>

  <script>
   import dragdrop from './dragdrop.js';
   export default {
       name: 'my-component',
       components: {},
       data: () => ({
          dragdrop : dragdrop
       }),
       methods: {
       dragStart(e) {
           this.dragdrop.dragStart(e);
       },
       dropIt(e) {
           this.dragdrop.dropIt(e);
       },
       allowDrop(e) {
           this.dragdrop.allowDrop(e);
       }
   }
  }
  </script>
```

dragdrop.js

```
function dragStart(ev) {
    ....
}
function dropIt(ev) {
    ....
}
function allowDrop(ev) {
}
```

I got this error when I start dragging:

```
VM12491 tickets:36 Uncaught ReferenceError: dragStart is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.ondragstart (VM12491 tickets:36)

VM12492 tickets:36 Uncaught ReferenceError: allowDrop is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.ondragover (VM12491 tickets:36)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: you don't actually need to put the dragdrop in your data object. Here's a better way:

```
  <script>
   import { dropStart, dropIt, allowDrop } from './dragdrop.js'; // ES6 object destructuring

   export default {
       name: 'my-component',
       methods: {
         dragStart(e) {
             return dragStart(e);
         },
         dropIt(e) {
             return dropIt(e);
         },
         allowDrop(e) {
             return allowDrop(e);
         }
     }
  }
  </script>
```

Answer: My guess is that you should probably return the functions that you want to run. It's hard to tell what the actual problem is with the HTML drag attributes without the actual HTML code though.

Comment: This method is almost the same with mine. this still doesn't work

Comment: Are you exporting the functions in your dropdown.js? `export default { dropStart, dropIt, allowDrop }`

Comment: Yes. " export 'dropIt' (imported as '_dropIt') was not found in './dragdropswap' ", same goes with the other functions

Comment: my bad. this works and so is mine. the problem is in the html props. thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

Export the function you need to use in the `Vue` component.

```
const dragStart = function (ev) {
    console.log(ev);
};

export default dragStart;
```

Now you can import it in `Vue` like

```
import dragStart from "./dragdrop";
```

and can be used inside the component like

```
created() {
  dragStart('test');
}
```